# How to execute sqlite test file?

Tags: sqlite, testing

I downloaded the sqlite3 source file (not amalgamation version)
There are test folder and many test files (journal1.test , pager1.test ... etc)

How to execute these test files?

Comment: I don't know all the ins and outs, but I believe some of the tests require a commercial component of some kind to run.  If you've not already seen it, have a look at [How SQLite is Tested](https://www.sqlite.org/testing.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, 
I have another question, many trace macro (such as WALTRACE , trace in pager) is printed only in testing mode?
I give the SQLITE_DEBUG compile option but nothing changed 
Do you know how to print the trace ?

Comment: Sorry, beyond my knowledge:-)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the SQLite's [download](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) page and download the `Snapshop of the complete (raw) source tree` on the `Alternative Source Code Formats` section.

Unzip it, `cd` into the folder and run:

```
sudo apt install tcl-dev zlib1g-dev
./configure
make test
```

You can run the quick test instead (less than 3 minutes):

```
make quicktest
```

Or just the tcl tests (aka veryquick):

```
make tcltest
```

---

### On Mac

```
brew install tcl-tk
./configure --with-tcl=/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib
make test
```

Comment: Just a quick comment, this is an old question / answer. If you're using an m1 mac, the configure path is /opt/homebrew/opt/tcl-tk/lib